# Figure with Tabular to illustrate an equation

Tags: floats, equations, multirow

I would like to the Dice Coefficient by creating from a visual point of view.
I.e.
The Dice Coefficient is expressed as:

```
 $D(A,B) &= \frac{2 \left| A \cap B \right|}{\left| A \right| + \left| B \right|}$
```

With Tikz I created illustration images using cloud and starburst shapes that I saved.
Now in simplified code I would like to do something like:

```
d(\includegraphics{A.png}, \includegraphics{B.png}) = \frac{ \includegraphics{A_union_B.png} } +  \includegraphics{A_union_B.png} }{\includegraphics{A.png} + \includegraphics{B.png}}
```

I wrote the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    D(&
    \includegraphics{./images/A.png}&
    ,&
    \includegraphics{./images/B.png}&
    )=
    &
    \multirow{3}[*]{}{\includegraphics{images/A_union_B.png} + \includegraphics{images/A_union_B.png} \\
    \hline \\
    \includegraphics{images/A.png} + \includegraphics{images/B.png}}
    % \frac{\includegraphics{images/A_union_B.png} + \includegraphics{images/A_union_B.png} }{ \includegraphics{images/A.png} + \includegraphics{images/B.png} }
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

which does not do what I expect.

I tried also to do it directly using tikz, I got some results but I miss manage the size which drives me to a point where I should have drawn some alphabet letters.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**-------EDIT-------**

Zarko's solution allows me to do what I wanted but did not arrived when I posted this question.

What I wanted to do is:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=1cm, width=1cm}
\[
    D\left(\adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/A.png},\adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/B.png} \right) = \frac{\adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/A_union_B.png} +  \adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/A_union_B.png}}{\adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/A.png} + \adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/B.png}}
\]
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- sorry, your question is not clear ... some sketch, what is desired result, would be very helpful
- you should extend your code fragment to complete small document
- I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=1cm, width=1cm}
\[
    D\frac{\left(\adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/A.png}\, , \adjustimage{valign=c}{./images/B.png} \right)}
          {\adjustimage{valign=c}{images/A.png} + \adjustimage{valign=c}{images/B.png}}
    = \adjustimage{valign=c}{images/A_union_B.png} + \adjustimage{valign=c}{images/A_union_B.png}
\]
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**:
After editing qustion is clear what you like to have. copying and compiling your new code from your edited question, I got desired result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
Yes it is almost that.
I cannot update my post at this very moment but I will ASAP.

Comment: In my case the fraction is on the right of the equal sign but I could derivate what I wanted to do from your implementation. Thank you very much.